# bootstrap-table value to change border-color of the head

Tags: css, bootstrap-table

I'm using bootstrap-table and I'm trying to change the color of the border of the table-head.

My code:

```
.table-bordered td, .table-bordered th{
    border-color: black !important;
}
```

It doesn't work :(

Comment: Are you sure your `<table>` has the class `table-bordered`? Could you provide a [mcve] of your problem?

Comment: You're right, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Here border-color will be overridden by th and tr, you have to set the color for all. Use the below code in your css and try:

```
table.table-bordered> thead > tr > th{
  border:1px solid black;
}
table.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```